# Keeping line breaks in HTML

Tags: javascript, html

**I have stored in DynamoDB this information as a string:**

1. Competitive salary
2. Accommodation allowance
3. Annual airfares allowance
4. Contract completion bonus
5. Extensive training and ongoing Professional Development.
6. Medical insurance
7. Full paid Christmas, summer and winter holidays

**However, when I retrieve the information with this code:**

```
    {initialValues.otherSalaryInformation && (
      <Typography
        color={status === "Expired" && "text.secondary"}
        component={"p"}
      >
        {initialValues.otherSalaryInformation}
      </Typography>
    )}
```

**It looks like this:**

1. Competitive salary 2. Accommodation allowance 3. Annual airfares allowance 4. Contract completion bonus 5. Extensive training and ongoing Professional Development. 6. Medical insurance 7. Full paid Christmas, summer and winter holidays

**What can I do to ensure the line breaks are present?**

**DynamoDB:**
[image: DynamoDB]
**Website:**
[image: Website]

Comment: How are you storing the line breaks in DDB? `\n`? DDB will store whatever you give it, you need to handle line breaks on your side.

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary, I've just added a new image to show the HTML

Comment: This is a HTML question then! Nothing to do with DDB if you have the line breaks in HTML but they are not visible.

Comment: the question is misleading.. the tags don't perfectly match and there are details not strictly bound to the real issue. To quickly solve the problem you could just style the html element with `white-space: pre-wrap;` that will preserve the spaces and new lines on its content. Otherwise you'd need a more fine tuned approach that will replace the newline in your string with `<br>` or just make that list a `<ul><li>` list after splitting the string by newlines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To obtain the correct spacing, I added this code to the `<p>` tag.

```
  style={{ whiteSpace: "pre-wrap" }}
```